# How to merge deleted folder back to main

Tags: git

I am having a school software project, my teammate accidentally deletes the Front-end(web) folder on the main branch, while deleting it on the back-end branch. We are trying to merge the web branch back to main, we merged web to the copy of mainhttps://github.com/siiulan/EasyQ/tree/copy_main/Frontend/EasyQ/public but the git failed to recognize the right folder, after the merge, the back-end code flows into the front-end folder, and what was in the web failed to get merged into the main. here is our git repository https://github.com/siiulan/EasyQ/tree/main/Frontend/EasyQ, can someone tell me what's happening, and how to fix it?

Comment: You can't "merge something back", you merge changes, not state. Your best option is probably to use the `git revert` command to revert the deletion of that folder. Essentially you would issue a `git revert ID-OF-DELETION-COMMIT`. Then, if that also reverts other changes you don't want to revert you restore the changes you want to keep in your local working folder, and use `git commit --amend` to fixup the revert commit to not revert those changes.

Comment: "my teammate accidentally deletes the Front-end(web) folder on the main branch" So just undo that. That's the whole point of Git; everything is stored (if committed) so everything is undoable, restorable, etc. But that has nothing to do with merge.

Answer (score -1):

you should normally be able to :

1. checkout to the commit before the mistake of your mate using checkout "hash of commit"
2. create a new branch out of that commit using git branch
3. merge the new branch with the main, to get back to a previous state.

Comment: Git does not merge state, it merges changes. If you simply create a branch from main/master from a point before something disastrous occurred, and then try to merge that branch back into main/master, git will tell you it is up to date, and do nothing. Since there was no changes on the new branch that wasn't already on main/master, git did nothing, as expected. There are many other options, however, such as removing the erroneous commit entirely from the history, likely using rebase, or to revert it. But simply merging a commit from before it, back into main/master will accomplish nothing.